# Find and Update MongoDB child elements conditionally

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have person with favorites and I want to add to their list of favorites without having duplicates.  I've attempted the following with Mongoose:

```
exports.favorite = function (req, res, next) {
    var favoriteItem = {
        uid: req.params.uid,
        name: req.params.name,
        phone: req.params.phone
    };

    Favorite.findOneAndUpdate(
        { cn: req.params.uid },
        { $push: { favorites: favoriteItem }},
        { safe: true, upsert: true}, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                process.stderr.write(error);
            }

            res.send('Saved successfully.');
            return next();
        });
};
```

How can I push favorites conditionally based on uid? Note, I'd like to create the record, should it not exist too with upsert.

Comment: Did you try $addToSet operator?

Comment: Sorry for the lame question: $addToSet is what I should be using instead of $push.